# Channel Offset lost count in multichannel Design Altium

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I was working on a multichannel design in Altium where a certain circuit is copied multiple times using room copy. Everything was fine until I modified the schematic by removing some parts and adding others. The problem is in channel offset. If I add a new component it takes a channel offset of another part in the room (as if the counter which knows at what channel the current offset is is lost). I corrected the problem manually but it is cumbersome that now every component I add has to be modified manually.

Does anyone know how to fix this?
is there a way to force an automatic reset of the channel offset of a certain room?

Version: Altium 23.11 updated to 24.2 same problem leading me to believe the corruption is in the project itself.

Comment: You can manually edit the channel offset for each component. But as this is purely a software issue and not about electrical design, this question seems to be off-topic here.